# "Did you" vs "Do you" for questions about the past

Tags: word-usage, american-english, past-tense

Which of these is more correct for American English in a professional context:

**Did** you have any other prior marriage that lasted at least 10 years, or any other prior marriage that ended due to your spouse's death?

**Do** you have any other prior marriage that lasted at least 10 years, or any other prior marriage that ended due to your spouse's death?

(I might also be tempted to change some other other grammar in this sentence if I had my druthers, but for the scope of this question, please focus on the first word.)

Comment: From the context of a native American English speaker, neither sentence is particularly appealing stylistically.  Both sentences sound awkward.  As you ask us to focus on the first word, I would choose **"Do."**  "Do you have any prior experience with computers?" "Did you have any prior experience with computers?" The latter may be grammatically correct, but it sounds awfully awkward to me.  "Were you" or "Have you" would sound far less awkward to my ears.

Comment: In the context of the sentences provided, it is difficult for me to focus on the root question.  "Did you" indicates that something was true in the past, where as "Do you" indicates that something is true in the present.  Including the word "prior" in the sentence increases the degree of difficulty a bit, but I still feel like "Do" is the most appropriate choice when discussing "prior" things.

Comment: If the marriage is over (which I think the use of prior confirms) then I believe that "Did" is the proper word to use. Once a marriage is over you no longer have it, you had it. If I was writing this sentence I would be temped to ask "Have you had..."

Comment: Why not "_have you been_ married for more than 10 years before"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Prior marriage* indicates that it is not a current marriage. That means it is not ongoing, but is something in the past.

*Did you have* means you *had* (owned, were in the state of, engaged in, etc.) but no longer *have* it. You *had* a prior marriage, but you do not *have* a prior marriage. *Did you have* is the interrogatory form of *you had*. It is correct.

*Do you have* would suggest that you currently *have* a prior marriage. You do not. It is prior, and you are no longer in it. *Do* would be incorrect.

It would be different if the question were phrased slightly differently, such as

> Do you have a history of prior marriage ...

In that case, you presently do have a *history* that could include things that are concluded, such as a prior marriage.

Comment: Excellent explanation of the technical underpinnings of why "Did" is correct. Thank you.